# Is it possible to use Database Views instead of Tables in Magento Resource Models?

Tags: module, mysql, magento-community, ce-1.9.0.1

I'm experimenting with developing an extension for Magento. I have the following scenario:

Database tables: `mydb_table1`, `mydb_table2`, `mydb_table3`, `mydb_table4`, `mydb_table5`

Database view: `mydb_view1` that collects the latest values from those tables, `mydb_view2` that collects any other value that isn't the latest

For flexibility reasons, I want to use database views as entities in my Resource Model in Magento. Since views and tables appear in different sections of the database schema, do I have to use the XML handle `<table></table>` for the views or can I use a XML handle like `<view></view>`? I have 2 different versions of my `etc/config.xml` file but none of them work:

First version:

```
<entities>
   <view1>  
        <table>mydb_view1</table>
   </view1>
   <view2>  
        <table>mydb_view2</table>
   </view2>
</entities>
```

Second version:

```
<entities>
   <view1>  
        <view>mydb_view1</view>
   </view1>
   <view2>  
        <view>mydb_view2</view>
   </view2>
</entities>
```

Any help or guidance would be appreaciated, because every tutorial that I find talks about tables but not about views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to reply to my own question: Yes, it's possible to use views in Magento as if they were tables. They work right away.

Comment: Can you let me know how to define the views in config.xml file

Comment: same as table entity :) late but may someone get help